# Oracle Query returned as Hasmap<String, String>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am making this query to an Oracle data base  `SELECT T109.DISTRITO FROM T109 T109`            , where the column DISTRITO has a lot of numbers. I want to take all this numbers and put them in an endpoint, so when they use it display this info in the format Hashmap  or Hasmap , etc... but always as Hashmap. How can I do it? Please, ignore the spanish words, I know we must always code in english, but this is inherited code. Here what I tried.

CODE

```
private final String CONSULTA_SOLO_DISTRITOS =
            " SELECT T109.DISTRITO  \n"
                    + " FROM T109 T109 \n";


 public HashMap<String, String> getOnlyDistritoTarificacion(String numero) {

        List<Map<String, Object>> filas_distritos = null;

        HashMap<String, String> distrito = new HashMap();

        filas_distritos = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(CONSULTA_SOLO_DISTRITOS, new Object[]{numero, numero});

        if ((filas_distritos != null) && (!filas_distritos.isEmpty()) || (filas_distritos.size() != 0)) {

            Map<String, Object> row = filas_distritos.get(0);

            distrito.put("distrito", (String) row.get("DISTRITO"));

            distrito.put("mensaje", "El n&uacute;mero consultado (" + numero + ") ya pertenece a un Distrito de Tarificaci&oacute;n.");

        } else {

            distrito.put("mensaje", "El n&uacute;mero consultado (" + numero + ") no pertenece a un Distrito de Tarificaci&oacute;n.");

        }

        return distrito;

    }
```

Comment: I think you should use 2 List to save each value (_distrito_ and _mensaje_), once you collected all the results, you will set the keys in the map, by join the List emenet, with your separator.

Comment: @MarioSantini what about if I only wanna put the distrito?

Comment: Then you only need 1 List object to collect your results.

Comment: @MarioSantini could you please show me how? I am new about this , thanks a lot  for spare your time in aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get this right, so please forgive me if this is wrong, I just try to help.

I think the issue with your code is that you continue to set the same Map key *distrito* with each number came from the query ResultSet.

Instead you should collect your values in a List object, and when you have allo of them set the value to your Map.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getOnlyDistritoTarificacion(String numero) {

    List<String> distritos = new ArrayList();

    HashMap<String, String> distrito = new HashMap();

    List<Map<String, Object>> filas_distritos = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(CONSULTA_SOLO_DISTRITOS, new Object[]{numero, numero});

    if ((filas_distritos != null) && (!filas_distritos.isEmpty()) || (filas_distritos.size() != 0)) {

        Map<String, Object> row = filas_distritos.get(0);

        distritos.add((String) row.get("DISTRITO"));
        distritos.put("distrito", (String) row.get("DISTRITO"));

    }

    distrito.put("distrito", 
                 distritos.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    return distrito;
}
```

So as you see you just add the values one time after you collected all of them.
I used *","* to concatenate, but you can use another character or string you need.

Also, you don't need to add the value for *"mensaje"* on each iteration, just make a check on the value you need to set:

```
boolean numberConsulted = true;

if ((filas_distritos != null) && (!filas_distritos.isEmpty()) || (filas_distritos.size() != 0)) {
    // .... code ...
} else {
    numberConsulted = false;
}


if (numberConsulted) {
    distrito.put("mensaje", "El n&uacute;mero consultado (" + numero + ") ya pertenece a un Distrito de Tarificaci&oacute;n.");
} else {
    distrito.put("mensaje", "El n&uacute;mero consultado (" + numero + ") no pertenece a un Distrito de Tarificaci&oacute;n.");
}
```

I don't know spanish, so sorry for the variable name, I hope the meanining is cleare, anyway just ask.

In your previous code you can have the wrong result.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for spare with me some of your time, I can work with this explanation. Grazie mille!